# KMS States on a $C^*$- dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $\omega$ be a $(\tau, \beta)$- KMS state of the $C^*$- dynamical system $(\mathcal{U}, \tau)$ with $\beta \in \mathbb{R}-\{0\}$. What is mean by the normal extension of $\omega$ to the weak closure  $\mathcal{M}_\omega=\pi_\omega(\mathcal{U})''$ of $\mathcal{U}$ in the GNS representation $(\mathcal{U}_\omega, \pi_\omega, \Omega_\omega)$.

How is it defined? Can I get a reference for this. I am stuck on the corollary 5.3.4 in the book Operator algebras and Quantum Statistical Mechanics 2 by O Brattelli and D W Robinson.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you do is simply define
$$
\hat\omega(x)=\langle x\,\Omega_\omega,\Omega_\omega\rangle. 
$$
This is a normal state, and for any $a\in\mathcal U$ you have 
$$
\hat\omega(\pi_\omega(a))=\langle \pi_\omega(a)\,\Omega_\omega,\Omega_\omega\rangle=\omega(a). 
$$

Comment: Okay. I have am in another situation. I have started with a $\beta$- KMS state $\omega$ and its normal extension $\hat{\omega}$ is a $(\hat{\tau},\beta)$- KMS state for $\mathcal{M}_\omega$ where $\hat{\tau_t}(\pi_\omega(a)=\pi_\omega(\tau_t(a))$ for all $a$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$. Now let $c \in \mathcal{M}_\omega$ be a central element. Then if I define $\overline{\omega}(a)=<c\pi_\omega(a)\Omega_\omega,\Omega_\omega>$ for $a \in \mathcal{U}$. I want to prove that $\overline{\omega}$ is a $(\tau, \beta)$ KMS state. Can I take $\hat{\tau}_{i\beta}(\pi_\omega(a))=\pi_\omega(\tau_{i\beta}(a))$?

Comment: Take $c_j\in \mathcal U$ with $\pi_\omega(c_j)\to c$. Then $$\bar\omega(a)=\lim_j\langle \pi_\omega(c_j)\pi_\omega(a)\Omega_\omega,\Omega_\omega\rangle=\lim_j\omega(c_ja).$$ Because $c$ is central the limit also agrees with $\lim\omega(ac_j)$. Then $$\bar\omega(\tau_{i\beta}(b)a)=\lim_j\omega(\tau_{i\beta}(b)ac_j)=\lim_j\omega(ac_jb)=\bar\omega(ab).$$

Comment: Why such a sequence $\pi_\omega(c_j)$ exists? I do not know much details about von Neuumann algebras. Is the convergence you said is SOT? What is actually mean by a central element

Comment: You won't understand much if you don't know the basics of von Neumann algebras. The net  $\pi_\omega(c_j) $ exists by the Double Commutant Theorem (so $\pi_\omega (\mathcal U)''=\overline {\pi_\omega (\mathcal U)}^{\rm sot}=\overline {\pi_\omega (\mathcal U)}^{\rm wot}$). The convergence is wot. "Central" means that  $cx=xc $ for all $x $.